# Rendering ExpressionEngine Tags in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, expressionengine

After much digging and searching about I haven't found a solution that allows for EE bracket tags to correctly render within javascript. It just renders the EE tag as text and not the actual code within the global snippet.

```
$config['remove_unparsed_vars'] = 'y';
var $containerHeight = $('.section-content').height();   
var widget = ('{list}'); 
if ( $containerHeight > 1500  ) {
    $('.widget-box').append(widget);
}
```

Any thoughts or feedback will be much appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ExpressionEngine rendering JS code with { } brackets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6514647/expressionengine-rendering-js-code-with-brackets)

Comment: You may do better asking over at http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick google found

`$conf[‘protect_javascript’] = ‘n’;`

and

[ExpressionEngine rendering JS code with { } brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6514647/expressionengine-rendering-js-code-with-brackets)

Comment: Appreciate it, but I found these and these did not work for me.

Comment: If you found them, help us not waste our time and tell us your investigation up front